# Is this a good design?How can I make it better?

Tags: c#

I have an existing class which looks like this:

```
public class MyUser
{
 public string Id { get; set; }
 public bool Status { get; set; }
 public MyUser GetUser(string param1, string param2)
 { 
  var user=new MyUser();
  //make db call based on param1 and param2 and pupulate MyUser object
  return user;
  }    
}
```

Now when I try to access this method:

```
 var myUser = new MyUser();
 myUser =myUser.GetUser(param1, param2);
```

Now, it's working fine, but my question is: is this written in a good way?Can it be better?if yes how?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: offtopic.. please move it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Then post to codereview, not stack overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: `GetUser()`  encapsulates a constructor, probably with a few additional operations. You could expose a constructor with the same parameters directly; that would be clearer. Such a "factory method"  can be justified if things are to be done which would be misleading to do in a ctor; or if the user returned is *not* simply a new object but instead, for example, taken from a pool of potentially existing ones. By the way, the method can and should be static.

Comment: Move your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. At very first instance after visiting your code, I suggests first separate your code, it seems you are mixing model and factory method in one go. Take off your ```GetUser``` method here in a way so you can also use dependency injection.

Comment: ```class MyUserBusiness(IUserService userService){ IUserService _userService; public MyUserBusiness(){_userService = userService} public MyUser GetUserBy(string param1, string param2){return _userService.GetUser(param1,param2);}}```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was not aware of separate codereview site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetUser()` method is something like a factory. The question is, why do you need to instantiate a `MyUser` just to get another `MyUser` object?

So I'd suggest to make `GetUser()` a `static` method:

```
public class MyUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public static MyUser GetUser(string param1, string param2)
    { 
       var user=new MyUser();
      //make db call based on param1 and param2 and pupulate MyUser object
      return user;
    }    
}
```

And then you can use it like that:

```
var myUser = MyUser.GetUser(param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to have models separate on business logic and Db, so I will end-up have Model named User

```
public class User
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public bool Status { get; set; }  
}
```

and have another class named UserRepository, UserService .. whatever

```
public class UserService {
 public User GetUser(string param1, string param2)
 { 
     //make db call based on param1 and param2 and pupulate MyUser object
     return user;
  } 
}
```

and use Dependency Injection to inject DbContext and later your UserService class

Answer (score 0):

The only change I suggest is to rename `MyUser` to something such as `UserRepository`.

Reason being, that class looks to be a way of loading users, and usually classes which perform those types of actions are called `UserRepository`, or `UserProvider`, that type of naming.

Naming is subjective, so feel free to call it whatever you like, but I would refrain from using `MyUser`.

Comment: I agree with this and generally it's bad design to name anything with `My`.